# Android Post Successful Login

Tags: android

I have a login screen set up.  On successful login I am implementing the below code and wanted to know if this is a best practice or if there is a better way to "change activity" once a user successfully logs in. In the below code snippet is how I'm currently changing to another activity during successful login.  Is this the right way to change activity?

```
if(password.equals(storedPassword)) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Congrats: Login         Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    dialog.dismiss();
    Intent intent = new  Intent(MainActivity.this, FragmentActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
} else {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "User Name or Password does not match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the right way of starting an activity.
However, make sure you run your login api call in a background thread (e.g. Async Task). In the return callback method you could run UI related code (in the main thread) by using the following method.

```
 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
            dialog.dismiss();
            Intent intent = new  Intent(MainActivity.this, FragmentActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You did it the right way. Just make sure you are making API calls in background. If you want then you can add animation code before

```
finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is correct.

My suggestion is to use `startActivityForResult()` method. `finish()` will be called from `onActivityResult()`

```
if(password.equals(storedPassword)) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Congrats: Login         Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    dialog.dismiss();
    Intent intent = new  Intent(MainActivity.this, FragmentActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent,LOGIN_ACTIVITY_REQUEST);

} else {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "User Name or Password does not match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Check which request we're responding to
    if (requestCode == LOGIN_ACTIVITY_REQUEST) {
        // Make sure the request was successful
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // set RESULT_OK from Login Activity when user is successfully
            // login using setResult(RESULT_OK);
            // Now we can call finish here
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```